# Importing of api's in React-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciDpW.png)

This is the code please help me to solve this problem, the image attached to this question shows the error, ThankYou

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

class AlbumList extends Component {
  state= {albums: [] };

  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
    .then(response => this.setState({albums: response.data }));
}
renderAlbums(){
  return this.state.albums.map(album => <Text>{album.title}</Text>);
}

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
  return(
    <View>
    {this.renderAlbums()}
    </View>
  );
}
}

export default AlbumList;
```

Comment: this is because you don't have internet connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your device has a network issue, check the status bar of your phone, you can see it in the screenshot you've provided

Check out your WIFI icon, it has a cross, most likely the underlying issue with your network error in the yellow box.

[image]

You'd have a better time if you placed your code in a try-catch, so that you can inspect the error.

```
componentWillMount() {


        axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
        .then(response => this.setState({albums: response.data }))
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }
```

Comment: No problemo hombre

Answer (score 0):

Your error says message says there was a network error when you run your axios.get, since you do not have a catch it has no way of handling the error. Try adding a catch and figuring out what is wrong with your network request.

for ex:

```
axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
.then(response => this.setState({albums: response.data }))
.catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Sure works.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

class AlbumList extends Component {
  state= {albums: [] };

  componentWillMount() {
       axios   .get("https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums")
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
      .then(response => {
        //console.log(response);
        this.setState({ albums: response.data });
      });
}

  render() {
  return(
    <View>
        {this.state.albums.map((album, key) => {
          return <Text key={key}>{album.title}</Text>;
        })}
    </View>
  );
}
}

export default AlbumList;
```